# Package Installation Error

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, trialforce

Hello All delegates,
                                While installing a package on trail force  i am getting these two  error.

Missing Organization Feature: PRM
Missing Organization Feature: CustomerSuccessPortal

Is there any solution for this . Help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately these both sound like they are the partner portal and customer portal in which case they have been deprecated since summer 13. Unless you are already a customer of the portals prior to summer 13 - you cannot create them anymore. You must now use [communities feature](http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf) (which is very powerful).

You might want to make sure that the package is not referencing these features (Partner Portal, Customer Portal)